# jQuery Tooltip with close button and animated, that fades in and out

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have been looking for a simple tooltip. I have been looking at qTip2 but it looks over complicated - but it nearly does exactly what i want.

Can it be done without a 'plugin' so to speak?

What I need is for it a tooltip that can be positions at any point around a div, left/right, and top/bottom.

I need it to be visible on page load, with a close button, then it fades out after 1 minute.

I also need it to be animated, so that it draws attention to the user, I have done this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dH6LS/465/

```
var glow = $('.confirm_selection');
setInterval(function(){
glow.hasClass('glow') ? glow.removeClass('glow') : glow.addClass('glow');
}, 1000);
```

I am new to jquery, any advise or help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this setTimeout, *for more see demo***

**Code**

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

```
   setTimeout(function(){
         $(".confirm_selection").fadeOut("slow")
          }, 5000);
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dH6LS/468/)